# Can the sum of $n$ consecutive primes be $n$ times a prime?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory, prime-gaps

I recently saw a "coffin problem" asking to prove that the sum of two consecutive primes is not twice a prime. This got me wondering if three consecutive primes can sum to be three times a prime, and they can. I figured out that it is possible if and only if the smallest and largest of the three primes sum to twice the middle prime (some examples are 3, 5, 7 and 47, 53, 59). I tried to figure out whether or not 4 consecutive primes can sum to be 4 times a prime, but I have made no progress.
So, I am wondering if it is known or possible to deduce for which values of $n$ can $n$ consecutive primes sum to be $n$ times a prime.

Comment: I have put an answer (too long for comment) dealing with primes in arithmetic progression, not necessarily consecutive. I think this will be a very hard problem, as the arithmetic progression criterion allows some control over the sum, and "consecutive primes" are very hard to get any control over.

Comment: For the case of $4$ primes , why did you not just apply a brute force search ? The smallest example satisfying your condition is $$113+127+131+137=4\cdot 127$$

Comment: I currently search a solution (with consecutive primes) with PARI/GP for all $n$ in the range $[3,10^4]$ and display also the high water marks (a new record for the smallest starting prime doing the job).  Upto $n=1\ 079$ , there is a solution with a starting prime not exceeding $513\ 157$.

Comment: Seems that there is a solution for every $n\ge 3$ , but as usual (in such questions) a proof seems to be out of reach. For non-consecutive primes , a proof might be possible.

Comment: For $3\le n\le 10^4$ , there is a solution (with consecutive primes!) such that the smallest prime in the list does not exceed $12\ 633\ 253$

Comment: @Peter My answer (really an extended comment) shows that it is indeed possible for non-consecutive primes. I have to use the Green-Tao theorem on primes in arithmetic progression to get there.

Comment: @MarkBennet OK.

Comment: Here is a thought - for given $n$ take any consecutive sequence of $n-1$ primes. For the next one to make the sum divisible by $n$, it must have a specific remainder  modulo $n$. Now if that remainder has a common factor with $n$ it is impossible. If not it is more likely than $\frac 1n$ at $\frac 1{\varphi(n)}$. But roughly $\frac 1n$ of sequences of $n$ primes "ought to" have total divisible by $n$ and that would suggest that one might find such a thing in the first $kn^2$ primes or even in $kn$ for some constant $k$ because the first $2n$ primes have $n+1$ options. Hard to see what next.

Comment: I basically just scrolled through a formatted list of primes looking for $4$ consecutive primes that were all $1\mod 6$ and in the form $p,p+6,p+12,p+30$. This led me to the sequence of primes $4591,4597,4603,4621$. There might be a smaller sequence.

Comment: For non-consecutive primes, all we have to do is take an even number of the form $2p$. Find all the Goldbach primes and the sum of all those is a multiple of $p$. Some of these can be consecutive as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Green-Tao theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primes_in_arithmetic_progression) tells us that there are arbitrarily long arithmetic progressions of primes. It does not allow us to control whether the primes are consecutive, so I don't think we know that there are arbitrarily long arithmetic progressions of consecutive primes. But for arbitrary arithmetic progressions the following can be found.

Since the sum of an odd length arithmetic progression is divisible by the number of terms, the answer is yes for $n$ odd, and the total will be $n$ times the middle prime.

For even lengths, if the first prime is $p$ and the common difference is $d=2r$ (the prime 2 is clearly not involved, so the difference will always be even), the sum of the progression will be $$np+(n-1)(n-2)r$$

Now $n=2m$, so $n$ has the common factor $2$ with $(n-1)(n-2)$, and you will need $m|r$ or equivalently $n|d$.

So to make this work for $4$ you need to find an arithmetic progression of length $4$ with common difference $4$ or $8$ or $12 \dots$ eg $17, 29, 41, 53$

We can use the Green-Tao theorem again. For example we know that there must be an arithmetic progression of primes of length $33$. If the difference is $d$, then $p, p+4d, p+8d, p+12d, p+16d, p+20d, p+24d, p+28d, p+32d$ is a sequence whose common difference is divisible by $8$. So we can pick out a subsequence of a long progression to get the common difference we need. If you investigate you will discover that such long sequences of primes in arithmetic progression can get very large and be hard to find - but we do know they are there.

I think you should be able to show that this works for any $n$ you choose.

Answer (score 3):

According to the Hardy-Littlewood $k$-tuples conjecture (the natural generalization of the twin prime conjecture) there should be infinitely many prime quadruples of the form $(p,p+6,p+12,p+30)$ and hence infinitely many solutions to the original problem.

While this remains a (most likely extremely hard) conjecture, it seems an interesting question whether we can still prove that infinitely often the sum of four consecutive primes is four times a prime (since this is strictly weaker than even this special case of the $k$-tuples conjecture).

In general, it should be relatively easy to find such a "linear parametrization" when generalizing to $n \ge 5$ so that we are done by the $k$-tuples conjecture. However, again it might be interesting to ask whether we can prove unconditionally that such primes always exist.

Comment: We also need that $p,p+6,p+12,p+30$ form consecutive primes, but this should be not critical. This idea can probably generalized to larger $n$ , but the existence of one solution is established upto $n=10^4$ anyway.